# Login to Flutter Facebook Login

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem with the facebook login with flutter.
I followed a lot of tutorials but it's from 2018, 2019, so it doesn't match the version of flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0.
the process works very well when I launch it redirects me to facebook I enter my details I log in as MyFacebookName, the problem is that when I click on Ok it redirects me to the login page and it does not register the user on my Firebase console. Here is the code

```
// Facebook connection configuration

  static final FacebookLogin facebookSignIn = new FacebookLogin();
  String _message = 'Login or logout by pressing the buttons below.';

  Future<void> _login() async {
    final FacebookLoginResult result =
        await facebookSignIn.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn box:
        final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
        _showMessage(''')
         Sign in!

         Token: ${accessToken.token}
         User id: ${accessToken.userId}
         Expires: ${accessToken.expires}
         Permissions: ${accessToken.permissions}
         Declined permissions: ${accessToken.declinedPermissions}
         ''');
        break;
      checkbox FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        _showMessage("login cancelled by user.");
        break;
      checkbox FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        "Something went wrong during the login process."
            "Here's the error Facebook gave us: ${result.errorMessage}");
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _logOut() async {
    await facebookSignIn.logOut();
    _showMessage('Logout.');
  }

  void _showMessage(String message) {
    setState(() {
      _message = message;
    });
  }
//connection button
_buildSocialBtn(
            () {
              _login();
            },
```

Comment: It may not be a direct answer to your problem, but you can check this article https://medium.com/@karlwhiteprivate/flutter-facebook-sign-in-with-firebase-in-2020-66556a8c3586 since the old Facebook login it's pretty much deprecated.